# to develop JSF webpages in jdeveloper11g

Tags: jsf, oracle11g, jdeveloper

I am new to JSF using JDeveloper 11g, I need to create an UI using it which will have a user creation form and on submitting the data will be stored in a bean file. How to proceed with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JSF with JDEVELOPER**:

[This](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/jdev/obe11jdev/ps1/adf_richclient/adfrichclient.htm) tutorial should help you starting to learn how to build JSF applications with JDeveloper.

Also a video tutorial [here](http://www.xs4all.nl/~andrejk/jdev/jdev-jsf.html).

**JSF Managed Beans**:

Short tutorial [here](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/managedbean.shtml).

Comment: Hi Cristian, I found your tutorial links very helpful.

Comment: @Cristian... how could i use links in the page that I am developing, suppose there is a link of create user in first facet and after clicking on it a create user form will get created in second facet on the page... how can i do that in jdeveloper 11g ? please help ... i have created the create user link and form so how could i connect that two and make it open in the same page but different facets...

Comment: @sudeep You can use a commandButton with an `action` on some bean's method, and in this `action` you can make visible the panel which contains the create user components...

Comment: .. the issue is how can i display an A(abc.jspx) page on B(xyz.jspx) where B has two facets(left and right). Left facet holds the link which on clicking opens the B(xyz.aspx) page on the right facet.... what I am able to do is on clicking the link the new page is opened over the same page on full screen...

Comment: Hi 
i am using ADF technology ....
I have an command link in which I have added and show popup behavior with a dialog to display a popup… if I add an action listener in  that command link that action listener never gets called ….
As I need that action listener to get the value of an attribute which is added in that command link.

How can I perform action listener and show popup behavior together or one by one when the command link is clicked?
Please help!!